# YouTrack - mail user referenced in custom field

Tags: youtrack

I created custom field "Reaction needed" which can contain unlimited number of users. I put an issues widget on dashboard with issues, when I'm referenced in this field - just to see if anyone needs me :) . But I need one more thing - to be mailed every time my person happen to be referenced in this field - only one time - when I got set. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow that will be invoked on Reaction needed.changed event. You can also check that Reaction needed.added contains your user.